# Any push back like function in python?

Tags: python

Sorry guys!!! pardon me. I'm a beginner in Python. I am writing the following code:

```
for line in file:
 if StartingMarker in line:
  # Here: I want to push back 'line' back in 'file'
    for nextline in file:
     if EndingMarker in line:
        # Do some Operation
print "Done"
```

How can I push 'line' back in 'file'?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you say "push 'line' back in 'file'", do you mean how to put it back in the variable currently held in memory named `file`, or how to write it back out to disk to the actual file?

Comment: Can you give some sample input? The answers provided so far (including mine) have different assumptions about a) whether start and end markers can be on the same line, b) whether you want lines in between start and end markers to be included, c) can there be multiple start/end pairs within the same file and how (or if) you want to handle them. And probably others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't push back, yield.

```
def starttoend(it):
  for line in it:
    if 'START' in line:
      yield line
      break
  for line in it:
    yield line
    if 'END' in line:
      break

l = ['asd', 'zxc', 'START123', '456789', 'qwertyEND', 'fgh', 'cvb']

i = iter(l)
for line in starttoend(i):
  print line
```

Just use the iterator again if you need more sequences.

Comment: From a "being nice to callers" perspective, I'd recommend making the first line of `starttoend` just `it = iter(it)`, so the caller doesn't need to manually call `iter` themselves on non-iterator iterables (allowing you to replace the `i = iter(l)` and `for line in starttoend(i):` with just `for line in starttoend(l):`). The cost is trivial when it's already an iterator, and it means it works equally well when passed a `list` or an open file object.

Comment: The amount of code in `starttoend` could also be halved (and the need for manually converting with `iter` removed) by using `itertools.dropwhile` to handle the effects of the first loop: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY8/bwIxDMX3fIq35ZBYCv2L1AEJ1g4tW9UhR5KeRS4@clbh@PJXkoLKZL/nn5/sbpCG43wcfeIWJC4Jc@hBbcdJYBN3h4aCU8o6j15MEmEXbUUyWSjAc0Kg6EDxH66CaWtrymAB/bFZvm80IkumsjnFZR0YyAVbzCLJQ6/fVvpK/kFAnZzZKRXwik9tequn0KfjNpcSfzeb5/7@4fHp@SV3@8P5lSFHnYX/bnLZ/tT6S6nbm28@CuWiLlGUKo8n4/gL "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

There's no iterator that I know of that you can start iterating over and then push an item that's been taken back into the iterator. But what you can do is create a new iterator (with [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)) that iterates over the current item and the remaining items in the original iterator. Something like:

```
import itertools

with open('some-input-file') as f:
    it = iter(f)
    for line in it:
        if StartingMarker in line:
            it2 = itertools.chain(iter([line]), it)
            for nextline in it2:
                if EndingMarker in nextline:
                    # Do some Operation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in file:
    if StartingMarker in line and EndingMarker in line:
        # look ma! no need to push back
```

EDIT:

```
for line in file:
    if StartingMarker in line:
        # do some operation
        if EndingMarker in line:
            # do some other operation
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually that may not work because here's the actual problem:

for line in file: 
 if StartingMarker in line: 
  # I'm doing few operations here
  # Here: I want to push back 'line' back in 'file' 
    for nextline in file:

Comment: @Humble Learner: you still don't need to push back

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in file:
    if StartingMarker in line:
        if endingmarker in line:
            #do operation
        else:
            for nextline in file:
                if EndingMarker in line:
                     # Do some Operation
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 12 years old but I found another answer to this in python3

If you manually make an iterator for your file with iter(...) you can use iteratortools.tee to fork the iterator and make a local copy to continue from that point without changing the parent iterator. It is important that you tee 2 itrs and that you return the OTHER one for your main loop to continue with.

This does mean you will go over the local lines twice unless you consume the recognized lines from the one you are going to return.  This is a useful function to do that

```
def consume(iterator, n):
'''Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely.'''
  collections.deque(itertools.islice(iterator, n), maxlen=0)
```

The other answer to this ofcourse is to write a line-buffering read that wraps your file and uses iter internally to be one line ahead of what it returns.   This would be similar to the char lookahead in a pascal "file window"

Comment: Without a code example, I'm unclear on what this gains you. The OP's case doesn't require or benefit from `tee` AFAICT.

Comment: tee gives you two iterators.  When you need to look ahead, you tee, look at one, and then continue with the other

Comment: Except the OP doesn't need to look ahead (as the generator function [Ignacio posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176067/364696) shows). That's the confusion. This seems slightly related to what the OP is doing, without actually solving any of their problems. And you definitely don't want to consume one `tee`-ed iterator before beginning on the other; that's got all the code complexity of `tee`, with *zero* benefits over just `list`ifying the iterator and reusing the `list` as needed.